# How do I keep my template with instafeed.js but pull my personal feed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am finally done with the homepage and portfolio page (for now) and have moved onto a page i'd like to load my instagram feed.  The template I like only pulls the "popular" page images and when I change it to pull my pictures fails.  The code to pull my feed stops working when I include the template items.  Why are they canceling each other?

**Note: Lots of code coming.  I'll label as clearly as I can**

The CSS:

```
/* main content - instagram
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#instafeed a {
  padding:5px 5px 1px 5px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position:relative;
}

#instafeed .likes {
  background:rgba(222,89,135,0.8);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:1em;
  position:absolute;
  color:#ffffff;
  right:5px;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  opacity:0;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:150px;
  text-shadow:0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    transition: opacity 100ms ease;
}

#instafeed a:hover .likes {
  opacity:1;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

The WORKING Script that pulls the "popular page photos"

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: 'fae4f4b283b44eabbe4186ff9911ef65',
  limit: 20,
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  after: function () {
    var images = $("@rbphotographs").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div     class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
});
feed.run();
```

The WORKING script that will pull my images:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'user',
                userId: myID,
                accessToken: 'myToken'
            });
            userFeed.run();
        </script>
```

I tried THIS to MERGE the two features:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'user',
                userId: my userID,
                accessToken: 'myToken'
  limit: 20,
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  after: function () {
    var images = $("@rbphotographs").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
});
            });
            userFeed.run();
        </script>
```

But it didn't work.  What is causing the cancellation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced with the same problem. You should add `http:` before `{{image}}`.

So working template wiil be:

```
template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="http:{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
```

UPDATE: https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/75